# calling a datalist update command within another update command

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to call a datalist2 update command inside another datalist1 update command,

datalist2 is totally separate and different from datalist1, however i want both to update together.

```
protected void DataList1_UpdateCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
     {

         //update stuff .......


         DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, new DataListCommandEventArgs( **What do i place here??** );
         DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, f);

    }
```

this is the void for datalist2

```
protected void DataList2_UpdateCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs f)
```

im very confused, i just want the DataList1_UpdateCommand to also execute  DataList2_UpdateCommand

thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update `DataList2` from `DataList1` then you need to give `EventArgs` of `DataList1`. Like This.

```
DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, e);
```

Comment: does that mean i dont need to initialize a new DataListCommandEventArgs?

Comment: i get the following error :  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object